# Are older copies of current standard-legal reprints playable again?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

As far as I know, standard format allows cards released within the last two year before the release of the current edition e.g. for now, Rivals Of Ixalan.

During the Ixalan edition, there was a new Duel Deck edition (Merfolk, Goblins) containing re-prints of much older cards. Are they legal in standard format although they were firstly released more than two years ago from now on?

Comment: Related: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/18534/how-should-i-determine-whether-a-deck-is-legal-in-a-particular-format

Answer (score 3):

It doesn’t matter if a card is a reprint or being printed for the first time. A simple and obvious example would be a basic land card; a Mountain would be a reprint of an old card; but it would be standard legal because it was printed in a recent set.

However, cards printed in Duel Decks are not necessarily standard legal. Duel Decks contain some cards that aren’t part of the current or recent block. Standard currently (in January 2018) consists of cards printed in Ixalan, Amonkhet, or Kaladesh block.

To determine if a specific card is legal, you can check Gatherer to see the listing.

Comment: It's worth noting that applies to duel decks, however the welcome decks and planeswalker decks are standard legal. This is less obvious for the welcome decks where the symbol is different.