# MTG: What set is Seelenruhe (Tranquility in German) from?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I recently picked Magic: The Gathering back up after a 15 year lapse. Currently making my way through what seems like a thousand cards from my childhood and entering them into a card database at [DeckBox](https://deckbox.org/). I happened upon a German card by the name of **Seelenruhe** and I'm trying to figure out what set/edition this card is from.

[image: My copy of Seelenruhe/Tranquillity]

I Google searched and found that seelenruhe means tranquillity in German. An image search, via Google, gave me an image of the same Seelenruhe that I have (plus a Jolly Roger added in?).

However, the image is from an Ebay account that is no longer hosting the image or product, and the Ebay website is written in what I think is German, which I can't read. Therefore, I can't figure anything out about the set/edition this card comes from.

Do cards written in a language other than English, belong to a set different than their English counterpart's set?

---

#### - Other Research -

- According to [CardKingdom](http://www.cardkingdom.com/catalog/view?search=basic&filter[name]=Tranquility), Seelenruhe most resembles Tranquility from the following sets/editions: [Alpha](http://www.cardkingdom.com/catalog/item/64250) - [Beta](http://www.cardkingdom.com/catalog/item/53251) - [Collectors Edition](http://www.cardkingdom.com/catalog/item/110919) - [Collectors Edition International](http://www.cardkingdom.com/catalog/item/111211)
- Following [How can I tell the difference between early Magic: The Gathering card editions?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/5120/how-can-i-tell-the-difference-between-early-magic-the-gathering-card-editions?newreg=c33a54366e204d5389a4cb9a83710684)

```
    Black Border -> No Right-Side Center Symbol -> Corner Curve Sharpness?
        Sloped -> Alpha
        Sharp -> Not Titled "Reconstruction" -> Beta
```

Comment: Obviously it is from Alpha or Beta, the corners look sloped to me, so I'd say Alpha.

Comment: @Vilmar I thought that at first, but Seelenruhe has a 1994 copyright date. *"Limited Edition cards have no expansion symbol, **no copyright date**, and no trademark symbols; the text on the bottom left consists only of an artist credit."* - [Wikipedia: Limited Edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited_Edition_%28Magic:_The_Gathering%29)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This card is a Revised German [Tranquility](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTranquility%5d). For English sets without a set symbol only Alpha and Beta have black borders. But when Magic started out whenever a Core set was printed for the first time in a language it had black borders. The first printing of German Magic cards was [Revised Edition](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Help/Core_Sets#Foreign_black_bordered_Core_Sets_.28Revised_and_4th_Edition.29), Strangely it seems that German Revised had at least 2 printings, one in black border and one in white.

Reference: [Revised German Tranquility on Scryfall](https://scryfall.com/card/fbb/221/de/seelenruhe)

Comment: The set is commonly called `Foreign Black Bordered`.