# Where can I find a list of Magic expansions?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, expansions

I always have problems to remember expansions.

I am looking for a cheat sheet list of all Magic expansion with symbol, name, year, border color and translated name (to french).

Where can I find it?

Comment: Regarding border color, that may be difficult to find since there are some general guidelines for what sets have what color border, but there are exceptions (especially with older sets). This question has some information on that topic: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/23709/mtg-what-set-is-seelenruhe-tranquility-in-german-from/23714#23714

Comment: You may find this guide from a previous question useful:  http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/5120/how-can-i-tell-the-difference-between-early-magic-the-gathering-card-editions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find the list of existing products along with their logo, symbol and release date on the [Magic's official card archive page](http://magic.wizards.com/en/products/card-set-archive).

The page is [available in french](http://magic.wizards.com/fr/products/card-set-archive) as well.

While this page doesn't contains informations about border colors, each products page links to the corresponding card gallery on the [Gatherer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Default.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the previous answer, [MTGSalvation](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Template:List_of_Magic_sets) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Magic:_The_Gathering_sets) have good lists.